# Write javascript code that works with client side javascript and server side NodeJs modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Browserify and lo-dash, do something special. Ok, but should like to be free from other vendor libraries or nodejs modules. I want to write reusable code. So, ...

I can write some javascript code. Also, I can write NodeJs code. Ok: I can write a module for NodeJs, for server-side code but at some point I need to write a NodeJs code to export, for example, a module.

```
var MyModule = function () {
    this.attribute = 666
}
module.exports = MyModule
```

But, ... it's a NodeJs module. If I try to include it in client page ...

```
<script src="lib/myModule.js">
```

I'll get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined'. Why? Maybe, because it's NodeJs code, and not Javascript. Ok but, ... Which are best practice to share same code in client and server side with NodeJs. Ok, I can share a javascript file, and use it in both sides. How can I write a module, that works with a javascript code, that I want to use also in client side?

What I am looking for, is:

Write some javascript code. **my_public_file**.js:

```
console.log('I am a javascript snippet')
```

Then, I want to write a module that works with same code. **my_module**.js

```
var lib_public_code = require('some/public/path/my_public_file.js')
var MyModule = function () {
    this.attribute = 666
}
module.exports = MyModule
```

And, also, I wanto to write a public web page (**index.html**) that works with the same code

```
<script src="javascript/my_public_file.js">
```

Best practices? I am insane?

Comment: This is what you need http://browserify.org/

Comment: My problem is on server side, not in client side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it work both client-side and server-side, just export it if `module.exports` exists:

```
var MyModule = function () {
    this.attribute = 666;
};

if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = MyModule;
}
```

This, and similar ways are used by a lot of libraries to enable packages to be used on CommonJS and the browser (e.g.: [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d837f119c3729565103005d5d7fa89e1dd8110cb/src/intro.js#L15-L38))

Comment: Couldn't you just do `var MyModule = module.exports = function MyModule(options) {}`

Comment: no, because on the browser you will get a `ReferenceError`. That will only work on server side, and thats not the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You install browserify

```
$ npm install -g browserify
```

you take your **my_public_file.js** whatever node code etc.

```
var lib_public_code = require('some_file.js')
var MyModule = function () {
   this.attribute = 666
}
module.exports = MyModule
```

you run the magic

```
$ browserify my_public_file.js -o bundled_public.js
```

then it works in the browser and the required files are all there.

```
<script src="bundled_public.js">
```

Comment: Ok but, ... the question is: how to write reusable javascript code, thus i dont need to browserify or lo-dash?

Comment: I think the point of browserify, webpack, and others, and bundling your code, and concatenating required files, is that it just handles all the things that would make managing cross platform code painful.  Browserify also has many of the modules you may already use on npm converted to browser compatible code,  typically the "module" ending in "ify".

Comment: Another point is just sharing configuration files between server and client sides.

Answer (score 0):

Use require.js both on client and on node.js. Already done several apps which shares the code between client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

To write a reusable javascript module. I will use the code below, which will work with browser, nodejs and requirejs.

```
    (function(root, factory) {
      if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
      } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
      } else {
        root.myModule = factory();
      }
    }(this, function() {
      var myModule = {};
      myModule.publicMethod = function() {};
      return myModule;
    }));
```

The `factory` function is being invoked and we can assign it to the relevant
environment inside. In nodeJs, `export.modules = factory();` . In requireJs,
`define([], factory);`. In the browser, `root.myModule = factory();`, because `root === window`, we can use `myModule` as a global variable.